# Sum over multiple IDs in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm creating an VAT invoice export for distribution via PEPPOL where there need to be a summary for all rows of a certain type deginated by the value in the node "itemref". I need a sum of the value in vatbaseprincipal_iso for these.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<export>
    <datalist>
    <currencycode>SEK</currencycode>
        <row>
            <itemref>208</itemref>
            <vatbaseprincipal_iso>695.0000</vatbaseprincipal_iso>
            <vatrate_iso>25.0000</vatrate_iso>
        </row>
        <row>
            <itemref>209</itemref>
            <vatbaseprincipal_iso>595.0000</vatbaseprincipal_iso>
            <vatrate_iso>25.0000</vatrate_iso>
        </row>
        <row>
            <itemref>206</itemref>
            <vatbaseprincipal_iso>1295.0000</vatbaseprincipal_iso>
            <vatrate_iso>25.0000</vatrate_iso>
        </row>
        <row>
            <itemref>099</itemref>
            <vatbaseprincipal_iso>15.8200</vatbaseprincipal_iso>
            <vatrate_iso>25.0000</vatrate_iso>
        </row>
        <row>
            <itemref>090</itemref>
            <vatbaseprincipal_iso>3370.0000</vatbaseprincipal_iso>
            <vatrate_iso>25.0000</vatrate_iso>
        </row>
    </datalist>
</export>
```

The node "itemref" can contain the values 09, 090 or 099 and I've been trying to get it working like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="vatrows" match="row[itemref = '09']|row[itemref = '090']|row[itemref = '099']" use="itemref"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/export/datalist">
        <Invoice>
            <TaxTotal>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="row[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('vatrows', itemref))]" mode="vatsum_vatrow"/>
            </TaxTotal>         
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="vatsum_vatrow">
                <TaxSubTotal>
                    <TaxableAmount>
                        <xsl:attribute name="amountCurrencyID">
                            <xsl:value-of select="../currencycode"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(translate(-1 * (sum(../row[itemref = '09']/vatbaseprincipal_iso) 
                            + sum(../row[itemref = '090']/vatbaseprincipal_iso) 
                            + sum(../row[itemref = '099']/vatbaseprincipal_iso)),',','.'),' ','')"/>
                    </TaxableAmount>
                </TaxSubTotal>  
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that I get two sums in the result since there are two different values, 090 and 099 in the input XML (I guess that the "key" function returns a new ID for each hit?).
This is the result from this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Invoice>
    <TaxTotal>
        <TaxSubTotal>
            <TaxableAmount amountCurrencyID="SEK">-3385.82</TaxableAmount>
        </TaxSubTotal>
        <TaxSubTotal>
            <TaxableAmount amountCurrencyID="SEK">-3385.82</TaxableAmount>
        </TaxSubTotal>
    </TaxTotal>
</Invoice>
```

What I want in this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Invoice>
    <TaxTotal>
        <TaxSubTotal>
            <TaxableAmount amountCurrencyID="SEK">-3385.82</TaxableAmount>
        </TaxSubTotal>
    </TaxTotal>
</Invoice>
```

(All this comes from the intricacies that the Peppol e-invoice standard does not really support VAT invoices so there are some tinkering to be done in the export for this thing to work. That's why, even though the vatrate_iso in the input XML is 25.000 for all the rows, we need to sum these specific rows up with zero percent tax. Otherwise I would have used the vatrate_iso column as key.)

Comment: Please reduce your code to [mcve] and add the expected result.

Comment: Updated the question with a working example, input data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/export ">
    <Invoice>
        <TaxTotal>
            <TaxSubTotal>
                <TaxableAmount amountCurrencyID="{datalist/currencycode}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="-sum(datalist/row[itemref='09' or itemref='090' or itemref='099']/vatbaseprincipal_iso)"/>
                </TaxableAmount>
            </TaxSubTotal>
        </TaxTotal>
</Invoice>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or, if you want to use a key for this, then perhaps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row" match="row" use="itemref" />

<xsl:template match="/export">
    <Invoice>
        <TaxTotal>
            <TaxSubTotal>
                <TaxableAmount amountCurrencyID="{datalist/currencycode}">
                     <xsl:value-of select="-sum(key('row', '09')/vatbaseprincipal_iso) - sum(key('row', '090')/vatbaseprincipal_iso) - sum(key('row', '099')/vatbaseprincipal_iso)"/>
                </TaxableAmount>
            </TaxSubTotal>
        </TaxTotal>
</Invoice>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both options could be streamlined a bit, depending on the exact processor you use.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! This simplified things quite a bit. I guess I had not grasped the workings of the "key" function. Thanks! :)

Comment: AFAICT, your attempt is modeled after [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html), and creates two groups of rows: those that satisfy the condition and those that don't. You then populate both groups with identical content.